# MS Access Choosing Filter with ComboBox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I have returned with yet another Question regarding MS Access and its VBA environment.

I'm currently constructing a database in MS Access 2016.
The main View `headview` has a combobox `viewcombo` and a subform `listview`.

What I need: I want the combobox to filter the listview depending on the chosen entry of it.

What I did:

```
Private Sub ViewCombo_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

If IsNull(Me.ViewCombo) Then

   Me.ListView.Form.Filter = ""
   Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = False

Else

    Dim selectedOption As AccessObject
    selectedOption = Me.ViewCombo
  Select Case selectedOption

   Case selectedOption = "open"
      Me.ListView.Form.Filter = "Column1='" & "'"

End Select

End If
Proc_Exit:
   Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
   MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " Setting Filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
   Resume Proc_Exit
End Sub
```

Note: The `Me.ListView.form.Filter = "Column1='" & "'"` is supposed to be empty if the chosen entry of `viewCombo` is `open`, the available entries are `Open, Closed, ovedue, cancel and "as seleced`

However, it seems that Access doesnt work this way. How do I properly write the select case statements?

**Edit 1:**
The Values of the ComboBox `ViewCombo` are manualy written in it. Depending on the selection of a value, different Filters are to be set on the `ListView`
Example:
The selected value is `open`
The Listview is filtered with the statement: `Column1 is empty`

The selected value is `closed`
The Listview is filtered with the statement `Column 1 is not empty, Column 2 contains the value 10` (10 is an ID for a status, these are given to me by the employees I work with, those are internal and have no meaning for the database)

Hope that helps to clarify the situation.

Comment: You say the available entries of the combobox are `Open`, `Closed`, `Ovedue`, `Cancel` and `As selected`. Please describe exactly which records you want to be displayed in the ListView subform regarding to each possible entry and how they technically could be filtered out (we don't know the fieldnames and fieldtypes of the datasource of your ListView subform yet).

Comment: @UnhandledException I edited the Question with an example, hope that helps to clarify the situation :D

Comment: @UnhandledException I solved it myself Thank you for your question, gave me the right Idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will use the value of the combobox, not the combobox as an object, similar to:

```
If IsNull(Me.ViewCombo.Value) Then

    Me.ListView.Form.Filter = ""
    Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = False

Else

    Select Case Me.ViewCombo.Value
        Case Is "open"
            Me.ListView.Form.Filter = "[SomeFieldName] = 'open'"   ' or other filter value.

    End Select
    Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = True

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the Input you guys gave me:

```
Private Sub AuswahlFilter_AfterUpdate()
On Error GoTo Proc_Error

If Me.ViewCombo.Value = "All" Then
   Me.ListView.Form.Filter = ""
   Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = False

Else
Select Case Me.ViewCombo.Value
    Case Is = "Open"
    Me.ListView.Form.Filter = "FlagOpenClosed='1'"
    Me.ListView.Form.FilterOn = True
End Select

End If
Proc_Exit:
   Exit Sub
Proc_Error:
   MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " when creating Filter:" & vbCrLf & Err.Description
   Resume Proc_Exit
End Sub
```

I created some additional Columns on the ListView. The Table `listview`is based on now has additional columns filled with values from statements like `When(IsNull(Column1);1;0)`. Then I set the filter for those values.

I guess there is a better way to do it, however, I am a noob in VBA, so that is the best solution I came up with. If there is a better way to do it, please dont hesitate to write it as an answer here, I am glad to learn new things, and love to hear from you guys.

-Ninsa