# Filtering microsoft access records based on a combo box

Tags: ms-access

I have a Microsoft Access database. It has a LOOP Table . I also have a form which includes all Loops and their info.

I want to make a combo box (drop down box) that would include the subsystem . When the user chooses a subsystem from the combo box, only the records which were added in that subsystem will show up in the records table.

Can this be done? I have been trying to do this for at least 5 days but no luck..

Kind regards.

Comment: What is a LOOP table? What do you mean by "will show up in the records table" - do you want to apply a filter to a form? Most anything can be done with enough code but it isn't clear what you want to do.

Comment: LOOP table , it's the table that generate by running my form

Comment: i want to add a combo box in my form ,and that for  when the user chooses a subsystem from the combo box, only the records which were added in that subsystem will show up in the LOOP table that will be generated by clicking in a button in my main interface

Comment: "records which were added in that subsystem" - added where? Perhaps edit your question to show sample data structure. Build text tables. Possibly you need an INSERT SELECT action sql.

Comment: i have a table composed by name of loop , subsystem , cable name .. etc so i  am trying to create a combo box in my form to chose a subsytem than only the records which were added in that subsystem will show up in the  table , i am not very good in english i hope u understand my problem

Comment: You want to use an unbound combobox to select criteria to filter a form. This is basic Access functionality. There is even a design wizard for that. However, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153877/ms-access-choosing-filter-with-combobox?msclkid=670c0b37c54211ecaa082b61767d9ef6. Your question is really too broad. Attempt code and when you have specific issue, post question.